# How to use a variable to pass the arguments in sequence

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Coding:

```
intVarNos=$#
strInp="Name1;Name2"
arrInp=(${strInp//;/ })

for ((i=0; i<=intVarNos-1; i++))
do
j=$((i+1))
echo "Value of " ${arrCTN[$i]} " is " $j
done
```

My requirement is to print the parameters or arguments in the following format

```
$./college.sh John Peter
Value of Name1 is John  
Value of Name2 is Peter
```

But I am getting the result as

```
Value of Name1 is 1
Value of Name2 is 2
```

The usual way to print the parameter is $1,$2.... How could I print the value of my parameter in this case. $$j doesnt works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash, you can perform an indirect lookup variable name lookup with:

```
${!j}
```

You could also assign the arguments to an array and then index the array.

```
args=("$@")
echo "${args[$j]}"
```